# Silently Uninstall Tomcat on Windows via Ansible

Tags: windows, tomcat, ansible, uninstallation, silent

**Ansible Control Specs**

```
OS:              RHEL 6.8 (Santiago)
Ansible version: 2.3.2.0
Python version:  2.6.6
```

**Target Machine Specs**

```
OS:             Windows 2008 Server R2
Tomcat version: 8.0.41
```

## Using win_package module (preferred)

I am trying to use Ansible to automate installing/uninstalling tomcat (so it needs to be done silently, without user interaction).

I am able to successfully install tomcat using the windows installer like this:

```
- name: Install Tomcat
  win_package:
    path: "https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.41.exe"
    product_id: "Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8"
    arguments: /S
```

However, I am having issues uninstalling the software. I tried using a similar approach as above (and adding the option "state: absent"), with no luck. I've tried downloading the installer, and using a local path. And also tried omitting the "arguments" option.

## Using win_shell module

I examined the registry key at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8` and saw the "UninstallString" property contains the following: `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\Uninstall.exe" -ServiceName="Tomcat8"`.

Of course, running this exact command manually on the target machine works, but running it via ansible will hang (since it is not silent).

**Adding "/S" argument to the end**

```
& "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\Uninstall.exe" -ServiceName="Tomcat8" /S
```

Running the command above does not work both manually and via ansible (same exact behavior). Both ways will delete the folders from tomcat root EXCEPT `bin`, `conf`, `lib`, `logs`, and `webapps`. Also neither option will remove the registry items or the tomcat service, and tomcat is still listed in the "Programs and Features" list.

**Adding "/S" argument to the middle**

```
& "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\Uninstall.exe" /S -ServiceName="Tomcat8"
```

Manually running the command above works perfectly (it leaves behind the `conf`, `logs`, and `webapps` directories but that's expected - see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/881730/full-silent-uninstall-of-tomcat-on-windows)). But running via ansible simply deletes the Uninstall.exe file from tomcat root - and that's it! It doesn't remove anything else from tomcat root, nor the registry items, nor the tomcat service. And still listed in "Programs and Features" list.

Here is the ansible syntax I am using:

```
- name: Uninstall Tomcat
  win_shell: '& "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\Uninstall.exe" /S -ServiceName="Tomcat8"'
```

Why do manual vs ansible commands behave the same when putting the '/S' at the end, but then behave completely different when putting the '/S' in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using win_shell to call the uninstaller, but I had to add a sleep at the end of the task.  Without the sleep, the only change which occurred was the removal of Uninstall.exe:

```
- name: Uninstall Tomcat
  win_shell: |
    $CMD = 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\Uninstall.exe'
    $arg1 = '/S'
    $arg2 = '-ServiceName="Tomcat7"'
    & $CMD $arg1 $arg2
    Start-Sleep -s 30
```

Comment: BTW, this is a variation of the original poster's solution attempt.

Comment: I had to stop the Tomcat8 service before running this un-install. It still left the service in a "Marked for deletion" state. turns out that the tray icon utility holds a lock on the service and therefore I had to kill the task: taskkill /F /IM Tomcat8w.exe.  But your ansible code is the only thing that actually triggers the un-install. Nothing else works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to successfully uninstall using the win_package module. You need to specify the Uninstall.exe file (inside tomcat root) instead of the original installer file.

```
- name: Uninstall Tomcat
  win_package:
    path: 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\Uninstall.exe'
    product_id: 'Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8'
    arguments: '/S -ServiceName="Tomcat8"'
    state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you prefer win_package, but I want to suggest using choco?

```
- name: Install Tomcat with Chocolatey
  win_chocolatey:
    name: tomcat
    state: present
    version: '8.5.12'

- name: Uninstall Tomcat with Chocolatey
  win_chocolatey:
    name: tomcat
    state: absent
  no_log: True
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/win_chocolatey_module.html
 https://chocolatey.org/packages/Tomcat/8.5.12